# Web Scraping in apps : What is the common way to account for changes in html of scraped website?

Tags: node.js, web-scraping

Im scraping a website in my app. The html mostly does not change, however it can happen. It in fact just happened that they changed the html/css a little bit which of course made scraping fail. I am wondering what the right approach is as with apps, you cannot just easily make changes and its immediately up to date like on websites.

my ideas are:

1. fetch the parts where I access the dom and store it in my db. Like that I can always change it in my db if the websites html changes. For example I would save this:

```
title: $item.find('header').find('h3').find('span:nth-of-type(2)').text()
```

2. Can I use environment variables for that?

Is there any common way to do this?
Thanks